# How to Create WCF proxy class given wsdl file

Tags: wcf, proxy, creation

I have wsdl file with me.But i don't have access to the file where it is deployed.
I need to generate proxy class using the WSDl file. I am getting error while using svcutil.ece to generate proxy file

> Error: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail:
>   Cannot find definition for
>   http://www.cii.com/Soa/Foundation:Basi
>   cHttp.  Service Description with
>   namespace
>   htt://www.cii.com/Soa/Foundat ion is
>   missing. Parameter name: name XPath to
>   Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.cii.com/Soa/Foundation/MessageDefinition.xsd']/wsdl:service[@name='CareerServicesS
>   ervice']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttp']

Thanks,
Shodhan

Comment: What exactly is your command line when you call svcutil?? Did you get any additional files, e.g. a second WSDL, or some XSD files, too??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using svcutil with a locally downloaded WSDL file, you need to also download all related XSD files and pass them on the svcutil command line as well. A great tool for automatically downloading all related XSD files is disco.exe in the Windows / .NET SDK (and there may be a svcutil mode that does it as well, don't remember for sure).